# Why can't orange be shown?

Tags: javascript, html

When I change the background color of the div element every second, the orange can't be shown.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var allDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div"),
    color = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "orange"];

function changeColor(){
  for(var i = 0; i < color.length; i++){
    (function(j){
      setTimeout(function(){
        allDiv[0].style.background = color[j];
        if(j === color.length - 1){
          changeColor();
        }
      }, 1000 * j);
    })(i);
  }
}
changeColor();
```

```css
div {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Go read this https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ then click this [edit] then add a repro to your question.  You might get it reopened and get an answer.  You won't by adding images of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the interval in `setTimeout`. The orange color might be getting set, but then immediately it would be changed because of the new call to `changeColor` - where in the first iteration, the interval for setTimeout is `1000*j = 0`.

Instead you could make it `1000*(j+1)`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   ...
}, 1000* (j+1));
```

Comment: OK.Thank you for your answer.My problem has solved.